# How to Add header and makes it as bold,align center for csv export in jQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to customize the CSV export in datatables to add a header and make it bold, aligned to the center? Can somebody help me out?

Comment: CSV is a text-only format, it does not know any such formatting.

Comment: you can do it with csv. but you can do that with excel. is possible to styling datatables export excel? yes.